Developer options crashes settings?
When I try to open developer options, the settings app just crashes. My device is a Nokia 3 TA-1032, running Android 9 (firmware version 00WW_5_230). Here is the log:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.settings, PID: 5147
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to set system property
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3847)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to set system property
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_set(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.set(SystemProperties.java:183)
    at com.android.settingslib.development.AbstractLogpersistPreferenceController.updateLogpersistValues(AbstractLogpersistPreferenceController.java:178)
    at com.android.settings.development.LogPersistPreferenceController.updateState(LogPersistPreferenceController.java:56)
    at com.android.settings.dashboard.DashboardFragment.updatePreferenceStates(DashboardFragment.java:317)
    at com.android.settings.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onResume(DashboardFragment.java:169)
    at com.android.settings.dashboard.RestrictedDashboardFragment.onResume(RestrictedDashboardFragment.java:137)
    at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2568)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1341)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1637)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3046)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3008)
    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:204)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7314)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3807)
    ... 11 more

Can someone let me know why this is happening? I think it's because I removed the Chinese "evenwell" apps that came with the phone (probably spyware).Thanks in advance for your reply.

Just be aware that flash memory does wear out and become unusable. On a device that old I would try to copy any important data off of it. If you re-flash/reset the OS that may work for a while but the device isn't trustworthy.

@MorrisonChang Sorry, I forgot to mention. The device had some Chinese "evenwell" apps on it (probably spyware) and I removed them. I think that's the cause. The flash memory is perfectly fine, the phone is rooted and has TWRP. I also removed all google apps and installed microG. I'm currently using this as my main phone as my other phones are not working, and it is quite reliable.

Nevermind, solved it myself.
Solution:

Go to Settings
Apps and notifications
Special app access
Modify system settings
Tap "Show system" from the three-dot menu
Select "System UI"
Toggle "Allow modifying system settings" off and then on.

Also, set SELinux to Permissive mode (needs root) using su -c setenforce 0. This needs to be done after every boot.
Hope this helps someone.
